# Python/ Beautiful Soap Data Extract Issue for Non Classed Items

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, data-extraction

I am trying to extract some data from the website. But the source of the website does not have classes for each item. I need the price quantitiy and size of the products.
Can you please guide me to find a solution for my problem?

I though that I can use the scroll menu to extract data for each products.Because that is the only class that I saw on the source of the page.  To sum up, I need to get data named as **data-comprice** **data-quantity**, and **data-size**. But could not find a solution yet. I am sharing my basic code and a part of the source page.
Thanks in advance!

Source:

```
 <div class="scrollmenu">
               
               

                
    
  <div data-value="2&#39; x 3&#39;" class="swatch-element 2-x-3 soldout ">
         <input data-comprice="75.01" data-curprice="30.00" data-size="2' x 3'" data-quantity="0" data-sku="AAAA0536-EPERNAY-23" data-price="30.00" data-title="2&#39; x 3&#39;" type="radio" name="id" value="31781284839506" id="radio_31781284839506"/>
        <label style="height:75px!important; min-width:135px!important; padding: 0 0px!important;"  for="radio_31781284839506">
          <p style="color: black; margin-bottom:0; font-size:15px; font-weight: bold;"> 2' x 3'</p> <br> <p style="color: #535258; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:-45px; text-decoration:line-through;"> $75.01  </p> <br> <p style="margin-top:-48px; margin-bottom:2px; color:#584c98; font-weight:bold; font-size: 20px;"> $30.00 </p>
        </label>
      </div>

 
    
    
    
              
                
    
  <div data-value="2&#39;7&quot; x 7&#39;3&quot;" class="swatch-element 27-x-73 soldout ">
         <input data-comprice="134.81" data-curprice="53.92" data-size="2'7" x 7'3"" data-quantity="0" data-sku="AAAA0536-EPERNAY-2773" data-price="53.92" data-title="2&#39;7&quot; x 7&#39;3&quot;" type="radio" name="id" value="31781284872274" id="radio_31781284872274"/>
        <label style="height:75px!important; min-width:135px!important; padding: 0 0px!important;"  for="radio_31781284872274">
          <p style="color: black; margin-bottom:0; font-size:15px; font-weight: bold;"> 2'7" x 7'3"</p> <br> <p style="color: #535258; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:-45px; text-decoration:line-through;"> $134.81  </p> <br> <p style="margin-top:-48px; margin-bottom:2px; color:#584c98; font-weight:bold; font-size: 20px;"> $53.92 </p>
        </label>
      </div>
```

My initial code block:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

webpage = requests.get('https://markandday.com/products/epernay-cottage-denim-rug')

sp = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, 'html.parser')

for datapage in sp.find('div',attrs={'class':'scrollmenu'}):
   
    
 
  Result=print (datapage)
  
  type(Result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find_all` method on `input` tag to get attribute from tag and for that `.get()` method is used

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html=""" <div class="scrollmenu">
            
  <div data-value="2&#39; x 3&#39;" class="swatch-element 2-x-3 soldout ">
         <input data-comprice="75.01" data-curprice="30.00" data-size="2' x 3'" data-quantity="0" data-sku="AAAA0536-EPERNAY-23" data-price="30.00" data-title="2&#39; x 3&#39;" type="radio" name="id" value="31781284839506" id="radio_31781284839506"/>
        <label style="height:75px!important; min-width:135px!important; padding: 0 0px!important;"  for="radio_31781284839506">
          <p style="color: black; margin-bottom:0; font-size:15px; font-weight: bold;"> 2' x 3'</p> <br> <p style="color: #535258; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:-45px; text-decoration:line-through;"> $75.01  </p> <br> <p style="margin-top:-48px; margin-bottom:2px; color:#584c98; font-weight:bold; font-size: 20px;"> $30.00 </p>
        </label>
      </div>
  <div data-value="2&#39;7&quot; x 7&#39;3&quot;" class="swatch-element 27-x-73 soldout ">
         <input data-comprice="134.81" data-curprice="53.92" data-size="2'7" x 7'3"" data-quantity="0" data-sku="AAAA0536-EPERNAY-2773" data-price="53.92" data-title="2&#39;7&quot; x 7&#39;3&quot;" type="radio" name="id" value="31781284872274" id="radio_31781284872274"/>
        <label style="height:75px!important; min-width:135px!important; padding: 0 0px!important;"  for="radio_31781284872274">
          <p style="color: black; margin-bottom:0; font-size:15px; font-weight: bold;"> 2'7" x 7'3"</p> <br> <p style="color: #535258; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:-45px; text-decoration:line-through;"> $134.81  </p> <br> <p style="margin-top:-48px; margin-bottom:2px; color:#584c98; font-weight:bold; font-size: 20px;"> $53.92 </p>
        </label>
      </div>

 """
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
inps=soup.find("div",class_="scrollmenu").find_all("input")
for inp in inps:
    print(inp)
    # inp['data-comprice'] you can also use this
    print(inp.get("data-comprice"))
    print(inp.get("data-curprice"))
    print(inp.get("data-quantity"))
    print(inp.get("data-size"))
```

Output:

```
<input data-comprice="75.01" data-curprice="30.00" data-price="30.00" data-quantity="0" data-size="2' x 3'" data-sku="AAAA0536-EPERNAY-23" data-title="2' x 3'" id="radio_31781284839506" name="id" type="radio" value="31781284839506"/>
    75.01
    30.00
    0
    2' x 3'
<input 7'3""="" data-comprice="134.81" data-curprice="53.92" data-price="53.92" data-quantity="0" data-size="2'7" data-sku="AAAA0536-EPERNAY-2773" data-title="2'7&quot; x 7'3&quot;" id="radio_31781284872274" name="id" type="radio" value="31781284872274" x=""/>
        134.81
        53.92
        0
        2'7
```

For website:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
html = requests.get('https://markandday.com/products/epernay-cottage-denim-rug')
soup=BeautifulSoup(html.text,"html.parser")
inps=soup.find("div",class_="scrollmenu").find_all("input")
for inp in inps:
    print(inp.get("data-comprice"))
    print(inp.get("data-curprice"))
    print(inp.get("data-quantity"))
    print(inp.get("data-size"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! But I need to connect to website, I can not insert HTML directly all products. I modified your code to use web site, but it did not work to eliminate data that I need. 

webpage = requests.get('https://markandday.com/products/epernay-cottage-denim-rug')
soup=BeautifulSoup(webpage.content,"html.parser")
inps=soup.find("div",class_="scrollmenu").find_all("input")
for inp in inps:
    print(inp)
    # inp['data-comprice'] you can also use this
    print(inp.get("data-comprice"))
    print(inp.get("data-curprice"))
    print(inp.get("data-size"))

Comment: i have edited my answer! and if you get any error please paste error not code in comment section